# Multiple object deselection when objects are overlapping

Tags: selection-tools

This might be very trivial, but I couldn't find an answer. I'm looking for a method to deselect one object when multiple objects are selected in object mode. If there is no overlapping (no other object behind the on I'd like to deselect), shift+clicking twice on an object works well, but when there's overlap it just cycles through the objects. I've read that ctrl+shift+clicking is supposed to deselect the currently active object but it does nothing for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> select:

[image]

<kbd>Alt</kbd> select: allows to choose the one to select in the menu.

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> select: allows to extend the selection or to set active in the selection (if not active) or to remove from the selection (if active).